# Intellij IDE terminal does not show accented characters

Tags: intellij-idea, character-encoding, terminal

I try to insert portuguese/spanish characters (example: á, ã, à, é, ú, ô, õ, ç) on Intellij's terminal, but they are not shown. How can I do it?

Comment: What font are you using?

Comment: @KarolS I'm using the default font of the Dracula theme.

Comment: Which is? Also, what do you mean by "insert"? Type, print, paste in? If type, then what's your keyboard layout and operating system, if print, then what's you default encoding? I recommend posting those info into the question itself; I may be unable to help, but then maybe someone else will be.

Comment: Hello @SidneyR.J. ! I'm facing the same issue here. Did you find a fix ?

Comment: It looks as if there is an issue logged here : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-126054#u=1402323835745

Comment: And another one here : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154068. Anybody affected please go and upvote the issue to give it some visibility.

Answer (score 0):

This has been finally fixed in `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1, Build #IC-163.9166.29, built on December 9, 2016`

Thanks to all the voters on JetBrain YouTrack :)