# How to have special/accented characters support in IntelliJ terminal

Tags: intellij-idea, zsh, zsh-zle

I use the [IntelliJ IDEA's Embedded Local Terminal](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/working-with-embedded-local-terminal.html) quite a lot, but there is one thing that is driving me nuts : special and accented characters do not work. 
This is what should but is not working :

- HOME key to go to the beginning of the line : does nothing
- END key to go to the end of the line : does nothing
- [CTRL + left arrow] to go to previous word : prints `D`
- [CTRL + right arrow] to go to next word : prints `C`
- all accented characters : prints nothing at first, then `?` when I hit another key

There are probably other combinations that should but  do not work ... but these are the most annoying ones.

I'm using :

- Ubuntu 16.04 virtual box guest running on a Windows 10 host
- IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.4
- zsh
- oh-my-zsh

Important notes :

- in a GNU Terminal (outside of IntelliJ then) everything works perfectly, so I don't think that the "running inside a VM" thing is the source of the problem.
- if I run bash instead of zsh the special characters are working (home, end, next work, etc...) but I still don't have propre support of accented characters (prints `�`), and I'd really prefer using zsh.
- `showkey --scancodes` prints `Couldn't get a file descriptor referring to the console`
- if I start `od -c` I get `^[[H` for the HOME key and `^[[F` for the END key
- `showkey --ascii` works and prints `^[[H` too for the HOME key

What I did already :

- checked that the `TERM` variable is not overridden in `.zshrc`
- add `bindkey "${terminfo[khome]}" beginning-of-line` and end of line equivalent in `.zshrc`
- add lines (that seemd appropriate) in .inputrc for `readline` (OK I see now that this was useless as Zsh does not use readline)

---

edit : I could make the home/end keys work (see accepted answer below), but not the CTRL+LEFT and CTRL+RIGHT key (for forward-word and backward-word). After some more digging this seems to be an issue with IntelliJ not 100% properly emulating the terminal. 4

There is an issue here, with interesting input from an oh-my-zsh contributor : https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-118848#comment=27-1292473

They consider ditching smkx (which appears to be the root of the problem) from oh-my-zsh soon. I've checked out [this PR](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/pull/5113) and now my keys work fine (still need the bindings, but CTRL+LEFT and CTRL+RIGHT are ok now)

---

edit: accented/special characters are now properly supported in IntelliJ (yeehaa !), be sure to have at least the following version : `IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3.1, Build #IC-163.9166.29, built on December 9, 2016`

Comment: Is the TERM variable being overridden in your ~/.zshrc ?

Comment: no it's not overridden

Comment: Ok, if forcing the scancodes is not working, I think the next step is to check, what keycodes readline is getting from within IntelliJ terminal. Can you please run `showkey --scancodes` and then press `Home` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: @AshutoshJindal: done : showkeys fails. Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: I can reproduce this problem on OSX (10.10.x) and Intellij Idea version same as yours. I know that you are using zsh, but can you check the following please.  Change the terminal in IntelliJ to bash (Preferences -> Terminal -> /bin/bash or equivalent) and reproduce the problem.  And then try editing the ~/.inputrc and add the following: `"\e[H": beginning-of-line` and `"\e[F": end-of-line` and then check if this fixes the problem for bash (it did for me). I am trying to isolate the problem (which seems to be a combination of zsh config and Intellij).

Comment: On OSX, inside Intellij terminal, I get different key codes than in an external terminal (iTerm) and using the key codes from IntelliJ in ~/.inputrc fixes it for bash atleast. Am trying to figure out what zsh does.

Comment: @AshutoshJindal: Thanks to your help I found a solution :). I put the result of showkey in bindkey and it solved the problem : for example `bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line` in my case.
.inputrc only works for readline, which is not used by zsh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can appreciate that zsh works fine outside IntelliJ.

#### Step 1

Find the correct key codes being used by the terminal inside Intellij. This will depend on the OS you are using. For OSX and Linux `od -c` followed by pressing the keys will result in the key code being emitted.

#### Step 2

Once you have the keycodes, modify your `~/.zshrc` :

```
bindkey "$HOME_KEY_CODE_FROM_STEP_1" beginning-of-line
bindkey "$END_KEY_CODE_FROM_STEP_1" end-of-line
```

for example (as was the case for the OP):

```
bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line
bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line
```

and restart the terminal.

Comment: I have already tried that (but retried just now to be sure) and it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Ok, I think the next step is to check, what keycodes readline is getting from within IntelliJ terminal. Can you please run `showkey --scancodes` and then press `Home` and paste the output in your question?

Comment: `showkey --scancodes` fails, but I tried with `showkey --ascii` and I got `^[[H` for the Home key

Comment: Thanks for all your help ! 

In my case it was `bindkey "^[[H" beginning-of-line` and `bindkey "^[[F" end-of-line` and I'll find the other ones. Maybe you want to amend your answer with the showkey step to find the codes.

Comment: Hum ... I've been at if for half an hour and can't get it to work with backward and forward word `bindkey "^[[5D" backward-word`
`bindkey "^[[5C" forward-word` ... same procedure as for the home and end keys. Any idea ?

Comment: And if you want to give a try to the accents, there is an unanswered question here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25003756/intellij-ide-terminal-does-not-show-accented-characters

Comment: Hmm, I was tripped by the fact that in some cases (combination of terminal, OS as well as the shell being used), the `\e` char must be used. So try using `bindkey "e[5D" backward-word`  or `bindkey "\e[5D" backward-word` ?

Comment: Nope doesn't work ... I've tried a lot of different combinations to no avail ... it's ... depressing ... why would the home/end keys work and not the CTRL+LEFT and CTRL+RIGHT keys not ... raaah it's so illogical

Comment: With your zsh, do you use any sort of layers on top? Like prezto or oh-my-zsh? Do you use the vim mode on the command line?

Comment: yes I use oh-my-zsh ... I do not use the vim mode, is it possible that this is enabled without my knowing ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123705/discussion-between-ashutosh-jindal-and-sebastien-nussbaumer).